# Retrofit2 204 No Content has content exception

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I get from server empty json ("{}") as a delete response with code 204.

In `okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine` class there is this annoying thing that gets thrown:

```
  if ((code == 204 || code == 205) && response.body().contentLength() > 0) {
    throw new ProtocolException(
        "HTTP " + code + " had non-zero Content-Length: " + response.body().contentLength());
  }
```

If you try return something without content (server side) in headers still Content-Length greater than 0;

Any non server side ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: why would the content-length greater than 0 with 204 ?

Comment: I don't know. it returns 2 for response "{}" and 2432 for empty content. (tried with Postman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be avoided if used differently a bit. Instead of:

```
@DELETE("vehicles/{id}/")
Observable<Response<BaseResponse>> deleteVehicle(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Path("id") Long vehicleId);
```

I use:

```
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "vehicles/{id}/", hasBody = true)
Observable<Response<BaseResponse>> deleteVehicle(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Path("id") Long vehicleId);
```

Comment: This one is better solution. I was aware of it for some time now, but i forgot about this question. :D

Answer (score 5):

You can trap the `ProtocolException` in an interceptor and return a placeholder 204 `Response`.  Caveats with this approach -- 1) you may end up trapping other protocol errors (too many redirects, etc).  If this is a concern, you could compare `e.getMessage()` to okhttp's exception message and rethrow the exception if there is not a match. 2) you still don't have access to the original response, so if you are out of luck if you need to inspect any of the returned headers.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
  @Override
  public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
      Response response;
      try {
        response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
      } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        response = new Response.Builder()
            .request(chain.request())
            .code(204)
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
            .build();
      }
    return response;
  }
});
```

Comment: I just might end up doing exact thing. I already have Interceptor for authentication so i guess i can add some extra stuff in that.